# Spark Mllib - FPG-Growth - Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark

Is the FPG-Growth an Machine Learning algorithm? Because I'm looking at this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt")

val transactions: RDD[Array[String]] = data.map(s => s.trim.split(' '))

val fpg = new FPGrowth()
  .setMinSupport(0.2)
  .setNumPartitions(10)
val model = fpg.run(transactions)

model.freqItemsets.collect().foreach { itemset =>
  println(itemset.items.mkString("[", ",", "]") + ", " + itemset.freq)
}

val minConfidence = 0.8
model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence).collect().foreach { rule =>
  println(
    rule.antecedent.mkString("[", ",", "]")
      + " => " + rule.consequent .mkString("[", ",", "]")
      + ", " + rule.confidence)
}
```

And I'm not seeing how the algoritm can learn because it don't have an train, test or validation set...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FP-growth is a frequent pattern association rule learning algorithm. Thus it's a rule based machine learning algorithm.

When you call the following :

```
val model = fpg.run(transactions)
```

You are actually creating and Frequent Pattern model without generating candidates. So actually you'll need to generate afterwards if you need to use them with :

```
model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence)
```

Now, concerning the usual flow of building and validating such models, your code doesn't deal with that. It's usually done through quality measures variations.

It can also be done through *Feature extraction techniques*.

With such techniques, you should consider the following. For each association rule, you'll need to measure the improvements in accuracy that a commonly used predictor can obtain from an additional feature, constructed according to the exceptions to the rule. In other terms, you'll have to select a reference set of rules that should help your model perform better. I strongly advice you to read [this paper](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~balqui/BalcazarDogbeyIDA2013.pdf) about the topic.

So now what does that mean ? This means that you'll need to implement that pipeline yourself because it's not implemented in Spark yet.

I hope that this answers your question.